# text adapting to button size

Tags: html, css

I had a problem where a text on a button went over the edge of the button. The text on the button was: "Thanks".  I solved that with adding the below to the code. This solved the problem.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="sign-up">
        <p class="sub-header">@Helpers.GetText(CurrentPage, "signupHeaderText", CurrentPage.Parent)</p>
        <form id="signupForm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="name">@Helpers.GetText(CurrentPage, "signupNameFieldText", CurrentPage.Parent)</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="@Helpers.GetText(CurrentPage, "signupNameFieldText", CurrentPage.Parent)" id="name" name="name" required />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="email">@Helpers.GetText(CurrentPage, "signupEmailFieldText", CurrentPage.Parent)</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="@Helpers.GetText(CurrentPage, "signupEmailFieldText", CurrentPage.Parent)" required/>
            </div>
            <input type="text" id="Channel" name="Channel" style="display: none;" />
            <input type="text" id="Campaign" name="Campaign" style="display: none;" />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default active">@Helpers.GetText(CurrentPage, "signupCtaButtonText", CurrentPage.Parent)</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn.btn-default.active,.btn.btn-default:active,.btn.btn-default:hover {
    background-color: #71a0af;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: none
    <!-- i added the below code to this class: -->
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 12px;
    width: 90px;
}
```

The problem is now that i discovered that another button is using the same class, but the text is here: "Yes please". That means that the button now is to small, and the text is flying over the side again.

What is the best solution on this problem? Should I make another class for the other button, or can I make it responsive, so that the button is adapting to the text?

Best Regards

Comment: If the button is completely drawn in CSS, it should be easy to make it surround the entire text, **if you avoid setting a fixed width for it**. If the button is a form button, it should also be big enough to contain the entire caption. But if it is a button pre-drawn as background image of, say, a `div`, you should consider the ["sliding doors" CSS technique](http://alistapart.com/article/slidingdoors).

Comment: Hello Rudy. Thank you for your answer. I just added the HTML. I can see there is some missing information here. What would you say would be the best solution here?

Comment: Do not use a fixed width. That seems to be important. You should probably use a min-width, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an excerpt of my `download` class (because I mainly use it for `download source code` or `download` buttons above an article):

```
.download
{
  display: inline-block;

  /* gradient */
  background-color: #627A85; /* old browsers */
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8A9FA9 0%, #4B5E66 100%); /* firefox */
  /* some other gradients removed here, for brevity */

  border: none;
  border-radius: 6px;

  /* some other settings here removed for brevity */

  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), -2px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px 12px 7px 15px;
}
```

As you can see: no fixed width. The main part is the padding and the use of inline-block.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your comment. I will try to see if I can use some of this. I can actually see now, when I run the site in my blisk browser, that my main problem is when I go to a mobile device. Then the text is not adpating, but keeps being the same size font.

Comment: Not right now. I can't currently use my computer, and this iPad is no good to view the source code. Perhaps tomorrow.

Comment: My home office is directly beside the guest room, and the noise of the keyboard disturbs the guests. So I went downstairs and use my iPad now. <g>